# Why, when I select "self collision" - the model shrinks (cloth simulation)

Tags: modeling, cloth-simulation

I have a problem with the cloth simulation. Here is the model's grid:

[image]

If I don't select "self collision" - everything is OK, but the model goes through itself.

[image]

But if I select "self collision" - the model shrinks.

[image]

Why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: did you check if you have any vertices duplicated?

Comment: @m.ardito Just checked, I think there is no duplicate vertices. Is there any other way to check, except for checking "by eye"?

Comment: @m.ardito 
But maybe that's the point! - I modeled this object again, and the problem disappeared. If you add this option as the answer, Iwill accept it, thank you!

Comment: No problem, anyway I'm happy you fixed it fast. it seemed to me that the whole object was self colliding with... itself... :D

Comment: @m.ardito Well, yes, perhaps)

Comment: @Rumata Yes, you can check if there are duplicate vertices and remove them. Go to edit mode, select all vertices and check for "Remove Doubles" buttons in the 'Tools' tab on the menu (Click 'T' to toggle this menu)

Comment: Also, when you are giving the collision/self collision, more often then not, unexpected behaviour (like shrinking, or explosion) happen when the collision distances and the distances in the model are very comparable. Make sure you understand the units of your scene while assigning collision distances. I stick to imperial units, my cloth objects are few feet in size and my collision distances are of the order of 0.2 units. Works well for me.