# Cloth simulation acting weird

Tags: cloth-simulation, geometry, versions

I am following a tutorial for making a Christmas hat, and my 'hat' acts slightly weird. Actually it compresses very strangely while there is nothing really paranormal in my settings.

**Does anybody know what causes the mesh to deform so weirdly?**

Before the simulation:

[image]

After few seconds(2s) of simulation:

[image]

Simulation settings:

[image]

Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xEp15H4AXfM

Comment: did you already check for duplicate geometry where it hrribly deforms? see also http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42822/why-when-i-select-self-collision-the-model-shrinks-cloth-simulation

Comment: If this hat has a "thickness", eg. if you applied a solidify modifier for example, this behaviour might occur, especially if some of your geometry intersects when the simulation starts, however slightly. I would try to simplify the model, and animate the cloth of the low-resolution model, instead. After that you can perform whatever prettifying model operations you want :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you dind't upload the .blend it is hard to tell what went wrong. I started with a circle extruded it and scaled the the tip before add some loop cuts.

Check the order of the modifiers

[image]

I also reduced the gravity and parented the hat to a sphere to see the deformation:

[image]

See the attached .blend for details and vertex groups

[image]

Comment: That certainly is a jolly result. Nothing is more seasonal than happy head coverings.